# Check if a certain Row existis, else select different row

Tags: sql, oracle

lets say I have a table containing

```
|vendor  | price| productID|  
|--------------------------------|  
|abc   | 6    | 0001     |     
|1     | 7    | 0001     |         
|def   | 8    | 0001     |      
|xyz   | 30   | 0002     |    
|zxy   | 32   | 0002     |
```

now I want to get the vendor which has the min() price for a product
for product 0001 that would be Vendor **abc**
for product 0002 that would be Vendor **xyz**

BUT! IF there is a Vendor named **1** I would like to see his name instead of the actual vendor with the min() price, if there is no Vendor named **1** for a product, I want to see the the one with the min() price again

if that makes any sense for you.. its kinda like a if-else construct but I dont know how to do it in SQL

(sorry for the bad formatted table, I just dont get it formatted the right way)

Thank you

Comment: Actually after re-reading a couple more times I am not sure. Did you mean for product = 0001, the vendor should be 1, but with what price? The price of 7 which is vendor 1's price, or still with the min() price of 6 (which is offered by a different vendor, not by vendor 1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  One method is to use `row_number()` and to put the rules for prioritization into the `order by`.  This resulting query:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by productId
                                order by (case when vendorid = 1 then 1 else 2 end),
                                         price asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This query does not meet the requirement. The requirement was to ALWAYS show the LOWEST price for a product. However, if vendor 1 sells that product, show 1 as the vendor NAME. This sounds like a "will match the lowest competitor price" arrangement. Also, as a separate matter, the vendor should be character type, and the `case` condition should use '1' (don't rely on implicit conversion from number to varchar2).

Answer (score 0):

The (currently) accepted answer does not meet the OP's requirement. The requirement was to show the minimum price for each product, even if vendor `'1'` does not have the lowest price. However, when someone else has the lowest price but vendor `'1'` also sells the same product, replace the vendor name with `'1'` (but don't change the lowest price to vendor `1``s price). This looks like "will meet my competitors' lowest price" type of arrangement.

**Query and output**:

```
with 
     price_table ( vendor, price, productid ) as (  
       select 'abc', 6  , '0001' from dual union all     
       select '1'  , 7  , '0001' from dual union all          
       select 'def', 8  , '0001' from dual union all 
       select 'xyz', 30 , '0002' from dual union all 
       select 'zxy', 32 , '0002' from dual  
     ),
     prep ( vendor, price, productid, rn, ct ) as (
       select vendor, price, productid,
              row_number() over (partition by productid order by price),
              count( case when vendor = '1' then 1 end ) over ( partition by productid)
       from   price_table
     )
select case when ct = 0 then vendor else '1' end as vendor,
       price,
       productid
from   prep
where  rn = 1
;

VENDOR   PRICE PROD
------ ------- ----
1            6 0001
xyz         30 0002
```

Comment: hi mathguy i didnt mean to replace the name of the vendor. i meant to say, that I need to see the minimum price and vendor name for a product. but if for a product, the lowest price is not by vendor 1, but vendor 1 is also selling it (for a higher price) I would like to see his price and name instead of the acutal lowest vendor. so basically I always want to see the vendor 1's  price, no matter if he is the lowest. but there will be products which he doesnt sell, then I DO want to see the actual lowest seller and his price... sorry for my bad english